# Solving the equation $a ^ b + b ^ a = 200$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, problem-solving

Find $a$ and $b$,

$a ^ b + b ^ a = 200$
One of the  answers is $a = 1$ and $b = 199$.

Lets say $a, b$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ then there will be many solutions, for each $a$ there exist $b$, in $\mathbb{R}$.

But how to find out $b$ for each $a$? I tried many ways, but not able to solve. Here is one of the approach I tried,

**Try-1**

$a ^ b + b ^ a = 200$
Take log on both sides

$b \log a + a \log b = \log 200$

After this I am not able solve (means all $b$'s are one side, and all $a$'s are another side)

**Try-2**

$a ^ b + b ^ a = 200$
(Trying for a special case, say $a = b$)

$a^a+a^a=200$

$2a^a = 200$

$a ^ a = 100$

Take log base 10 on both sides

$a \log a = \log 100$

$a \log a = 2$

stuck here, and not able to solve and not able to find $b$.

Comment: What makes you think it can be solved algebraically?

Comment: For your try 2 there is a solution in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):
$$a=\frac{\ln 100}{W(\ln 100)} \approx 3.59728502354$$

Comment: Your attempt in try #1 will not lead you anywhere.  The logarithm is not a linear function. That is to say, $\log(X+Y) \neq \log(X) + \log(Y)$.  So your first step of taking the logarithm of both sides is incorrect.  
That being said.... I'm still thinking of a way to get the actual solution

Comment: It is a naive belief held by those who have done high school algebra for too long that every equation can be "solved" so that you have a nice expression for one variable in terms of the others.  In fact, this is far from being the case.  Usually when you have some irregular equation like $\ln x + 10 = e^x$ or $3 \sin \sin \sin x + \arctan x = 2$ there is no easy way to express the solution, and trying to find one can be a waste of your time.

Comment: In this case, I've been messing around with the Lambert W-function trying to find $a$ in terms of $b$.  It looks promising, but no luck so far.

Comment: Pretty easy to rule out any more positive integer solutions with a calculator and 1 minute. Not really suprising.

Comment: Unless someone can prove me wrong by finding an explicit solution in the form of the Lambert W function or some other expression I don't think this problem is interesting. For any positive $a$ one can show there is a $b$ such that the equation is satisfied. Implicit function theorem and all that will show it is $C^1$. Use a numerical method.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a very hard one, and I don't think you can solve it with the elementary functions. The problem is that logarithms of sums don't play nice.

Also, you made this error in try 1

$$\log(a^b+b^a)\ne b\log(a)+a\log(b)$$

For your special case $a=b$, there's a solution which was noted by [gammatester](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/61216/gammatester),
and it is
$$a=\frac{\ln100}{W(\ln100)}\approx3.597$$

I solved the pairs numerically using [newtons method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

There's a function which turns one of the pair into another, it's plotted below

The function is going to be its own inverse

[image: plot]
[image: plot]

This function looks like $\frac1x$, it even seems to have the same limits, lets compare those

[image: plot]

What happens if change the $1$ to something else so it's equal at one place? I know the function has the solution $a=1$ $b=199$ so lets try $\frac{199}{x}$.

[image: plot]

While that did cross our function at 199, it didn't really act like the function..

So I tried some other things like logarithms, it looks a bit more like the function, but I'm giving up now.

Also here's a mathematically impractical, but useful for approximations solution to your problem.

Define the sequence below:
$$a_0=1$$
$$a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{a_n (\lambda^{a_n}+a_n^\lambda)}{a_n \lambda^{a_n} log(\lambda)+\lambda a_n^\lambda}$$
Then the function which transforms one from a working pair $(a,b)$ into another
$$f(\lambda)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n$$